# Heroku not logging in

Tags: heroku

I have been trying to make a website. I tried to do the
`heroku login`
command in terminal but it says `-bash: heroku: command not found`. I don't know why this is going on. Can someone please help?

Comment: You have to install it. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli#install-the-heroku-cli

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the Heroku CLI.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli

Please note as well, Heroku recently had some security issues, so you may need to reset your password if you haven't already.

https://status.heroku.com/incidents/2413

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning this, I already installed the Heroku CLI before.

Comment: @JustACoder It looks like it hasn’t been installed correctly. You could try restarting your computer. Or try re-installing it